# Inconsistent NFT transfers?

Tags: transactions, erc-20, nft, erc-721, address.transfer

I am fairly new to the blockchain.  My understanding of an `ERC-721` NFT is that it should be passed atomically between **addresses**.

In particular, if I track the **"from"** and **"to"** fields of an NFT, and when I look at transactions across time, I would expect to see something like:

```
from -> to
==========
A    -> B
B    -> C
C    -> D
```

This is usually true, but there are exceptions.  For example, in examining the following NFT, it appears to "**teleport**" from one wallet to another:

- https://etherscan.io/nft/0x11bCfAe88954f2961389658f5e57bE3B4d83D03E/10074

This is not an isolated case. Could anyone help me understand what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is difficult to explain in a few lines, but to understand just the transfer workflow, `ERC-721` **standard** is based on the **fungible token standard** `ERC-20`, so both of them provide the following functionality:

> Transfer tokens from one account to another, get the current token counts of an account and approve whether a third-party account can transfer tokens.

In addition, ERC-721 tokens provide the following functionality, which is unique to NFT:

> Get the owner of the specific token

Then it  could be said ERC-20 and ERC-721 has **two workflows to transfer** tokens from one address to another. The **first workflow** is used when the owner transfers tokens, and it is implemented in the `_transfer()` internal function as below:

```js
/**
 *  Transfers `tokenId` from `from` to `to`.
 *  As opposed to {transferFrom}, this imposes no restrictions on msg.sender.
 *
 * Requirements:
 *
 * - `to` cannot be the zero address.
 * - `tokenId` token must be owned by `from`.
 *
 * Emits a {Transfer} event.
 */

function _transfer(
    address from,
    address to,
    uint256 tokenId
) internal virtual {
   require(ERC721.ownerOf(tokenId) == from, "ERC721: transfer from incorrect owner");
    require(to != address(0), "ERC721: transfer to the zero address");

    _beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);

    // Clear approvals from the previous owner
    _approve(address(0), tokenId);

    _balances[from] -= 1;
    _balances[to] += 1;
    _owners[tokenId] = to;

    emit Transfer(from, to, tokenId);

    _afterTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);
}
```

The **second workflow** to transfer tokens is used when a third party transfers tokens using the `transferFrom()` function on behalf of the owner.

```js
function transferFrom(
    address from,
    address to,
    uint256 tokenId
) public virtual override {
    //solhint-disable-next-line max-line-length
    require(_isApprovedOrOwner(_msgSender(), tokenId), "ERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved");

    _transfer(from, to, tokenId);
}
```

In other words, the `transferFrom()` function is checking if any of the following conditions is true or not:

> - The **msg.sender** (who is calling this function) is the owner.
> - The **msg.sender** has been approved to transfer the token on behalf of the owner.
> - The owner has approved the **msg.sender** to transfer all their tokens.

The **first condition** is 'true' when the owner calls the transferFrom() function. It means that we can use the transferFrom() function in the transfer workflow we looked at in the previous section.

The `getApproved()` function is used in the **second condition**, which simply looks up the `_tokenApprovals` private variable.

```js
function getApproved(uint256 tokenId) public view virtual override returns (address) {
    require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721: approved query for nonexistent token");

    return _tokenApprovals[tokenId];
}
```

The `_tokenApprovals` variable is a **map of a token ID** and an `address`.

```js
// Mapping from token ID to approved address
mapping(uint256 => address) private _tokenApprovals;
```

So, the owner needs to call the approve() function first for the second condition to be true. It will add the spender address and the token ID to the the _tokenApprovals variable, so the _isApprovedOrOwner() internal function will return true.

In the **third condition**, the `isApprovedForAll()` function checks if the owner has given **msg.sender** a blanket approval to send their tokens.

```js
function isApprovedForAll(address owner, address operator) public view virtual override returns (bool) {
    return _operatorApprovals[owner][operator];
}
```

It looks up the _operatorApprovals private variable, a map of maps.

```js
// Mapping from owner to operator approvals
mapping(address => mapping(address => bool)) private _operatorApprovals;
```

It is updated by the **setApprovalForAll()** function via the _setApprovalForAll() internal function:

```js
function setApprovalForAll(address operator, bool approved) public virtual override {
    _setApprovalForAll(_msgSender(), operator, approved);
}
```

To resume, for the third condition to be true, the owner would need to call the setApprovalForAll() function to give the msg.sender approval in advance.

> If any of these three conditions is true, the transferFrom() function calls the _transfer() internal function, and it performs the transfer, as explained in the previous section.

```js
// To set as approved
function _setApprovalForAll(
    address owner,
    address operator,
    bool approved
) internal virtual {
    require(owner != operator, "ERC721: approve to caller");
    _operatorApprovals[owner][operator] = approved;
    emit ApprovalForAll(owner, operator, approved);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Gonzalo! I take it you are suggesting that the second workflow was used, and either the 2nd or 3rd condition was triggered.  Is there any way to confirm that?  Should I be deducing this from the "ApprovalForAll" events here: https://etherscan.io/address/0x11bcfae88954f2961389658f5e57be3b4d83d03e#events

Comment: Yes, it could be, let me update my answer to include it! @Bill Bradley

Answer (score 1):

The specific token you are talking about is a spam token. Its purpose is to notify as many people as possible that "YOU GOT A FREE TOKEN" so that it can trick you into putting your attention onto something that probably does not deserve your attention.

See contract code at https://etherscan.io/address/0x11bCfAe88954f2961389658f5e57bE3B4d83D03E#code

And specifically

```
  function emitTransfers(uint256[] calldata tokenId, address[] calldata from, address[] calldata to) external onlyOwner { 
       require(tokenId.length == from.length && from.length == to.length, "Arrays do not match.");
       for(uint256 i = 0;i < tokenId.length;i++) { 
           if(_owners[tokenId[i]] == address(0)) { 
              emit Transfer(from[i], to[i], tokenId[i]);
           } 
       }
    }
```

Here the owner of the contract, spammer 0xbfb12a8d07bb458dc05bef8edc5425da54651c4e, is broadcasting `Transfer` events willy nilly.

The contract is not enforcing any particular need that these tokens have continuity between the last TO address and the next FROM address.

One additional reason people do this is so that it can appear if some well-known person is the TO address. Some automated tools will pick up on this and mark this transaction as being an endorsement on the TO person to the CONTRACT.

Of course this is a scam because the TO person had no agency in the transaction.

Comment: Thank you! I've been pretty confused about the motivation and much appreciate your comments.  So are you suggesting, like Gonzalo Cugiani, that the contract ran `setApprovalForAll()` at some point so the NFTs could be transferred willy-nilly?  That's a great theory, but how do I find some record of that event on the blockchain?

Answer (score 0):

NFTs are digital assets, and you can transfer them to others(personal wallets or smart contracts).at first NFTs mint to the token creator(owner), and after that, they can transfer anywhere for deposit, selling or other transactions.
based on your link, the first and the last transaction show that, for better understanding and tracking the route of this token you can see [this link](https://etherscan.io/token/0x49cf6f5d44e70224e2e23fdcdd2c053f30ada28b?a=10074).

Comment: Thanks, Payam, but I'm still confused-- how is the NFT in your link related to the original one?  I see that they share the same `TokenID`, but what else do they have in common?  The time stamps also seem a bit unrelated.  (In other words, how'd you find your link?)

Comment: you can search NFTs with their TokenID in etherscan, as you saw this NFT mint 330 days ago and after that, it had an Auction in  "https://looksrare.org/" ( we can understand it because of "match ask with taker bid" transaction, after this process it moves to openSea a transfer in that,what is your problem about timestamp? lots of time the owner is one person( 278 days approximately)

Comment: I think my confusion is that my link pointed to a "PARIS BLVCK" NFT, whereas your link pointed to an "RTFKT" NFT.  They're different NFTs, right?